# Is there a way to create content groups within a Firebase Web+App project?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

I want to create content groups for different types of pages (e.g. football, tennis, rugby) within my web+app property.

Following the steps on how you would normally create these groups in a Google Analytics project, see steps below, I run into the issue that web+app properties do not have a VIEW column. So I cannot create these content groups this way. Is there a way to do this? I cannot find any other documentation on the topic.

- Sign in to your Analytics account
- Click Admin, and navigate to the view you want.
- In the VIEW column, click Content Grouping. //there is no VIEW in web+app
- Click +New Content Grouping.
- Enter a name for the new grouping.
- Select the methods you want to use (tracking code, extraction, or rules) to create Content Groups.

However the following screenshot indicates to me that there is some way to get Content Groups in a Web+app property:
[screenshot of web+app property with location of Content group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afTdW.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is no designated variable for content groups in an App + Web property, but you can accomplish the same goal with a simple event parameter.

I recommend adding your content groups under “Fields to Set” in the Configuration tag so that they will be set with every event. Then open the “All Events” report and “Edit parameter reporting” as shown below to enable the content group in your “page_view” event report.

[image]

https://ken-williams.com/guide/overview/migrating-tags-from-universal-analytics-to-app-web/